# Custom RSS feed reader/opener in Firefox?

Tags: rss, firefox, feed-reader

I would like to configure Firefox to open RSS feeds in a web-based reader (Feedbin).

The default page allows me to change between 'Live Bookmarks', a native application, or 'My Yahoo!'.

It won't be surprising to hear that I don't use Yahoo, but this seems to be the default and only web-based option - how can I change that list, to remove Yahoo and add Feedbin?

On Mozilla Developer Network, there is [a page describing how to add a feed programmatically from a web application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/2/Adding_feed_readers_to_Firefox) - less than ideal, but better than nothing, so I tried it in the console:

```
navigator.registerContentHandler(
    'application/vnd.mozilla.maybe.feed',
    'https://feedbin.com/?subscribe=%s',
    'Feedbin'
)
```

> X "SecurityError: Permission denied to add https://feedbin.com/?subscribe=%s as a content or protocol handler"

Answer (score 0):

Ah! D'oh, the error was preventing cross-site adding of feed readers.

Loading up feedbin.com, then running the same snippet through the console worked fine - a popup appears at the top of the window asking for confirmation, and now 'Feedbin' appears directly beneath 'My Yahoo!'.

This works, hence leaving it as an answer, but I would still be interested in a configuration-based solution - since I don't know that this will persist across FF Sync?